# Java input with optional string

Tags: java, string, input, int

I am currently working on an assignment where the input is going to be from a text file.
The problem i am running into is figuring out how to collect the input yet still break it up and make sure i have all the relevant data.

The input is :

Input 1:
1 book at 12.49
1 music CD at 14.99
1 chocolate bar at 0.85

Input 2:
1 imported box of chocolates at 10.00
1 imported bottle of perfume at 47.50

Input 3:
1 imported bottle of perfume at 27.99
1 bottle of perfume at 18.99
1 packet of headache pills at 9.75
1 box of imported chocolates at 11.25

I need to keep the first number, whether its imported, the name(i.e. bottle of perfume) and the price. Any suggestions would be lovely Im sure that regex is the answer but im not quite sure how to make it so that if imported comes up that the rest will still be read the same.

Comment: Nice assignment. Yes, regex can be a tool for this. Try something, and it might just work. If it doesn't, then come back and ask a question regarding your _attempted solution of the problem_. Of course, you'd have to research regexes, by for example googling "regex tutorial" first... [FAQ]

Comment: You need to decide what reliable delimiters you have. It seems that the word `at [price]` might be one, whilst `[1st number] until whitespace` might be the other.

Comment: Is `imported` optional? do you always have `at` before the price?

Comment: I have attempted using a regex tutorial and quite frankly i am not getting the concept. But to answer your question imported is optional and at is always before the price

Comment: Also Stewart i appreciate that probably should have specified that i am not figuring out how to do the optional character of imported yet still yield the rest of the results in correct sequencing

Comment: well, look at my latest answer...the fiddle should give the correct output...

Answer (score 0):

well, you could either do it by yourself, or you could be lazy and use this code:

```
var string = "1 book at 12.49 1 music CD at 14.99 1 chocolate bar at 0.85";

var data = getArray(string);

console.debug(data);

function getArray(string){
    //prepare the string
    //adding terminators (";")
    string = string.replace(/(at) ([0-9]*).([0-9]*)/g,"$1 $2.$3;");
    string = string.replace(/; /g,";"); //remove whitespace after terminators
    string = string.substring(0,string.length-1); //remove last terminator

    var split = string.split(";"); //split it up
    var data = new Array();

    //loop through objects
    for(var i=0;i<split.length;i++){
        data[i] = new Array();

        var subData = split[i].split(" ");

        data[i]['count'] = subData[0]; //0 is count
        data[i]['price'] = subData[subData.length-1]; //last is price
        data[i]['article'] = "";
        for(var j=1;j<subData.length-2;j++){ //in between is the name (minus the "at")
            data[i]['article'] += subData[j] + " ";
        }
    }

    return data //and done
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3sNBJ/1/

...i bet there would be better solutions, but i'm not very good with regex either...

[edit] ...oh, imported is a needed value too...well, http://jsfiddle.net/3sNBJ/3/

[edit2] ...now with ui: http://jsfiddle.net/3sNBJ/5/